# moodle page not working after installed local plugin

Tags: php, moodle

I am using moodle 3.2 version . I have installed local plugin. After installing that plugin some pages not working. Please suggest your solution.

Comment: Turn on debugging ( https://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging ), check web server error logs, remove the local plugin

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your upgrade.php is working correctly? Do you have one, you can just change stuff in your install.xml.

Have you cleared cache?

Did you follow naming conventions, so you dont create conflict with other plugins?

Comment: Yes i did everything. problem is folder format in plugin .